# Vercel Deploy fail

Tags: next.js, vercel

can anyone help me to fix this, im encountering this error when i am trying to deploy website in vercel

```
error - ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from. Referenced from: /vercel/path0/.eslintrc.json
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
warn  - The following reserved Next.js pages were detected not directly under the pages directory:
/api/_app
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/nested-reserved-page
Failed to compile.
./pages/api/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../styles/globals.css'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
./pages/api/auth/signup.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../model/ConnectMongo'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
Deployment completed
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

here is my .eslintrc.json, note that i didnt include any .babelrc in my project folder:

```
{
  "extends": ["next/babel", "next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```

and here is part of my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "eslint-plugin-next": "^0.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^10.11.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-request": "^5.2.0",
    "mongodb": "^5.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "next": "^13.3.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.20.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "swiper": "^9.1.1",
    "swr": "^2.1.1",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

I have tried to edit eslintrc.json according to other stack overflow solutions, but its not working